# Python WPF in VS wont give output

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio

I have made a very simple GUI using ironpython in visual studio.

Once I click the button I would like to see a print of "hello world".

However, the code dont give any output of the print.

The .py:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication2.xaml')

    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
        print('hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

The XAML:

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication2" Height="300" Width="300"> 
       <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="47,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Update:

It works only if im not in the folder of the project and I select to build the current file. any idea why?
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: where would you like to see "hello world"? o.O in the debug output?

Comment: No place in visual studio where I can see the result of the code like in pyCharm? how can I check If code works without moving to command prompt?

Comment: Let say I have a button and a textbox in my GUI and I had like to see text appears when I clicked the button. It is possible to see?

Comment: sure. you could call MessageBox.Show("method called!"). dont forget to add from System.Windows import MessageBox.